# How can I make independent steering for each antenna subarray in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do independent steering for each antenna subarray as below:

```
c = physconst('LightSpeed');
fc = 183e6;

antenna = phased.CrossedDipoleAntennaElement;
array = phased.URA([4 4], [1 1], "Element",antenna)
subarray1 = [1  1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ; 0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ; 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0; 0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1];
partitionedarray1 = phased.PartitionedArray('Array',array,...
    'SubarraySelection',subarray1);
viewArray(partitionedarray1)
steerang = [10,20,30,40]
partitionedarray1.SubarraySteering = 'Phase';
steeringvec_replarray = phased.SteeringVector('SensorArray',partitionedarray1,...
    'PropagationSpeed',c);
w = steeringvec_replarray(fc,steerang);


pattern(partitionedarray1,fc,[-180:180],0,'PropagationSpeed',c,...
    'Weights',w,'CoordinateSystem','rectangular',...
    'Type','powerdb');
partitionedarray1.SubarraySteering = 'Phase';
stv = phased.SteeringVector('SensorArray',partitionedarray1);
steer_ang = 30;
w = step(stv,fc,steer_ang);
pattern(partitionedarray1,fc,-90:90,0,'Type','PowerdB','SteerAngle',steer_ang);
pattern(partitionedarray1, fc, 'ElementWeights', w)
```

Steering seems do be working only for entire array even partitioned.

How can I steer separately each subarray?

Answer (score 0):

Solution.
Beams cannot be steered in case of partitioned arrays so walkaround is to replicate array into bigger one.

Last example on this side from mathworks library:
[Replicated subarray documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/phased.replicatedsubarray-system-object.html)